# web view not updating when pushed from table view

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, ios4, uiwebview, uinavigationbar

My current app consists of Navigation with Tabs, then a Table View in between, from the Table Rows when selected a Detail View is pushed. The issue I'm having is when I select a row it pushes to the Detail View and loads the html file in the Web View. However, when I navigate back and then select another row, it loads the same html from the previous selection. The only thing that stays relevant is the Title in the Navigation Title Bar.

Is this poor memory management on my part (I'm new to ObjC.. like only a week) or did I miss a step? I think me grabbing NSString *navDate = self.title; is my problem. Everything else basically works otherwise. Anyways, be gentle and thanks. :$

Table Cell

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *CellID = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellID];
if(cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
            initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault
            reuseIdentifier:CellID];
}
cell.textLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:15];
cell.textLabel.text = [self.dateList objectAtIndex: [indexPath row]];
return cell;
}
```

Row Push

```
(void) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger row = [indexPath row];
if(self.aTextController == nil){
    ATextController *aTextDetail = [[ATextController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ArchiveData" bundle:nil];
    self.aTextController = aTextDetail;
    [aTextDetail release];
}
aTextController.title = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateList objectAtIndex:row]];
SLESDAppDelegate *delegate = (SLESDAppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
[delegate.navigationController pushViewController:aTextController animated:YES];
}
```

DetailView

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
NSString *navDate = self.title;
NSString *null = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", navDate] ofType:@"html"];
if(null != nil){
    [webArchView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", navDate] ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]]; }
else {
    [webArchView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are retaining the instance of `ATextController` and reusing it, you will have to execute the following snippet in `viewWillAppear:` -

```
NSString *navDate = self.title;
NSString *null = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", navDate] ofType:@"html"];
if(null != nil){
    [webArchView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", navDate] ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]]; }
else {
    [webArchView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"error" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]];
}
```

The reason being that `viewDidLoad` is called once when the view controller loads its view. `viewWillAppear:` will be called every time the view is about to come on screen.